# Trouble with getting magento attributes while checkout

Tags: magento, attributes, checkout

Help pls with getting magento attribute while checkbout. I have 'only_registered' attribute. I trying to get attribute via this code:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cart as $_item){
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct());
  $registeredonly = $_product->getRegisteredOnly();
}
```

but this code generate magento error.

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1";i:1;s:4723:"#0 /work/www/topps.loc/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see the following error in code:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct());
```

Should be:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
```

And I see you said the variable name to be 'only_registered' so you should access it by:

```
$registeredonly = $_product->getOnlyRegistered();
```

And if that doesn't works simply do:

```
$registeredonly = $_product->getData('only_registered');
```